# How to hide played & deleted podcasts in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

All,

ITunes requested an update yesterday, and now a large number of past episodes of podcasts that I listened to & deleted appear in the podcast list (with the little cloud icon).  Is there anyway to hide those?  They clutter the podcast list tremendously.

Comment: relevent? https://discussions.apple.com/message/23036403#23036403